# Display values from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

When the user clicks a button I want the below data to be displayed on my webpage in the following format:

car1 - id:1346 - type BMW

car2 - id: 1379 - type Holden

etc...

How exactly would I go about doing this?
I tried this:

`document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = car1`

But all that was displayed was '[object Object]'

```
    var car1 = {id:"1346", type:"BMW"};
    var car2 = {id:"1379", type:"Holden"};
    var car3 = {id:"2580", type:"Ford"};
    var cararray = [car1, car2, car3];
```

Comment: You  need to use JSON.stringify on an object to display it in text form.

Answer (score 0):

You can access information of the car by using `.<property>`, where `<property>` in this case is either `.id` or `.type`.

To get all of the cars, you need to loop through `cararray`, and on each loop add it to the message.

```js
var car1 = {id:"1346", type:"BMW"};
var car2 = {id:"1379", type:"Holden"};
var car3 = {id:"2580", type:"Ford"};
var cararray = [car1, car2, car3];

var message = '';

for (var i = 0; i < cararray.length; i++) {
    var car = cararray[i];
    
    message += "car" + (i + 1) + " - id:" + car.id + " - type " + car.type + "\n";
}

alert(message);
```

`alert(message)` is used as an example, you can replace this with `document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = message`, and use `<br />` instead of `\n` when appending a car to the message.

Comment: Unsure why this got downvoted since OPs problem was displaying '[object Object]' when using "document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = car1". The car array wasn't part of the question

Comment: 1: Don't use jsfiddle if you can just use snippets. 2: you're ignoring the fact the OP has multiple cars he wants to render.

Comment: @Cerbrus Answer changed and feedback noted. Thanks

Comment: Much better! Note that `\n` won't work if the OP wants to add this `message` to his HTML.

Comment: @Cerbrus Edited

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you using a bulleted list (`ul`) and just append elements from the `cararray` array.

```js
var cararray = [{id:"1346",type:"BMW"},{id:"1379",type:"Holden"},{id:"2580",type:"Ford"}], 
    content = document.getElementById('message'),
    btn = document.getElementById('btn');

cararray.forEach(function(v,i) {
    var el = document.createElement('li');
    el.innerHTML = `car${i+1} - id: ${v.id} - type: ${v.type}`;
    content.appendChild(el);
});

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    content.style.display = 'block';
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<button id='btn'>reveal list</button>
<ul id='message' hidden></ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have explicitly wright what variable you wan't to render, you can't transform an object to string.
You can do this like this :

```
document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "id:" + car1.id + " - type " + car1.type
//Return id:1346 - type BMW
```

or like this :

```
document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(car1)
//Return {"id":"1346","type":"BMW"}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a loop to iterate your array and display what you need

```js
var car1 = {
  id: "1346",
  type: "BMW"
};
var car2 = {
  id: "1379",
  type: "Holden"
};
var car3 = {
  id: "2580",
  type: "Ford"
};
var cararray = [car1, car2, car3];

function display() {
  let message = "";
  cararray.forEach((car,i)=>message += "car"+(i+1)+" - id:"+car.id+" - type "+car.type+"</br>");
  document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = message;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="display()">Display</button>
<p id="message"></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function myFun()
    {
        var car1 = {id:"1346", type:"BMW"};
        var car2 = {id:"1379", type:"Holden"};
        var car3 = {id:"2580", type:"Ford"};
        var cararray = [car1, car2, car3];
        var cart="";
        for(var x=0; x<cararray.length; x++)
        {
          if(x==cararray.length)
            cart = cart + "car"+x+ "- id:"+cararray[x].id+" - type "+cararray[x].type;
          else
            cart = cart + "car"+x+ "- id:"+cararray[x].id+" - type "+cararray[x].type+ "<br>";
        }
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = cart;
    }
    </script>
    <head>
    <body onload="myFun()">
    <div id="message"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Try this simple solution. hopefully, it will work for you!

Comment: May i know reason for downvoting ?

Comment: Divyesh: Imagine what this code would look like if you had 100 cars... Why aren't you using the `cararray`?

Comment: This solution just for this particular question sir.

Comment: i know looping concept but it might be complicated to understand for this kind of question

Comment: @Cerbrus OP didn't request that car array should be used. He gave an example, that wasn't working, and our solutions addressed the issue to this problem. Upvote for the correct solution

Comment: If a loop is too complicated, you really shouldn't be answering JS questions.

Comment: @TobyMellor: You're kidding, right? Sure it works, just like rolling may eventually get you to the top of the mt. Everest. It's just not how it's done.

Comment: I am answering this question based on the user.

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm sorry, I'm confused. The question asks what the problem is with simply displaying "car1", and asks how to display "car1" in the given format. `cararray` wasn't even part of the question. The question was asking why it is displaying [Object object]

Comment: Stack Overflow is meant to be a repository of _quality_ Q/A. This answer is a very poor approach at solving the OP's problem. _You_ asked why this was downvoted. I answered, trying to give you some advice. If you don't want to hear my advice, don't ask for it.

Comment: @TobyMellor: So the OP isn't trying to render _multiple_ cars?

Comment: okay, i am trying to improve my answer.

Comment: @Cerbrus He provided the code `document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = car1`, which was fixed as requested

Comment: done! check it guys :)